# Segmentation fault error due to MPI_comm_size

Tags: c, fortran, mpi

I have a Fortran code which is design to run with the default communicator `MPI_COMM_WORLD`, but I intend to run it with a few processors only. I have another code which uses `MPI_comm_split` to get another communicator `MyComm`. It is an integer and I got `3` when I printed its value. Now I am calling a C function in my Fortran code to get the rank and size corresponding to `MyComm`. But I am facing several issues here.

1. In Fortran, when I printed `MyComm`, its value was 3, but when I print it inside the C function, it becomes `17278324`. I also printed the value of MPI_COMM_WORLD, it's value was about `1140850688`. I don't know what is the meaning of these values and why did the value of `MyComm` change?
2. My code runs properly and creates the executable, but when I executed it, I got the segmentation fault error. I used `gdb` to debug my code and the process terminated at following line

Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.

```
#0  0x00007fe5e8f6248c in PMPI_Comm_size (comm=0x107a574, size=0x13c4ba0) at pcomm_size.c:62
62      *size = ompi_comm_size((ompi_communicator_t*)comm);
```

I noticed that `MPI_comm_rank` gives the rank corresponding to `MyComm`, but the issue is only with `MPI_comm_size`. There was no such issue with `MPI_COMM_WORLD`. So I am unable to understand what is causing this. I checked my inputs but I did not get any clue. Here is my C code,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "utils_sub_names.h"
#include <mpi.h>
#define MAX_MSGTAG 1000
int flag_msgtag=0;
MPI_Request mpi_msgtags[MAX_MSGTAG];

char *ibuff;
int ipos,nbuff;

MPI_Comm MyComm;
 void par_init_fortran (MPI_Fint *MyComm_r,MPI_Fint*machnum,MPI_Fint *machsize)
{
 MPI_Fint comm_in
 comm_in=*MyComm_r;
 MyComm=MPI_Comm_f2c(comm_in);
 printf("my comm is %d \n",MyComm);

  MPI_Comm_rank(MyComm,machnum);
  printf("my machnum is %d \n ", machnum);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MyComm,machsize);
  printf("my machnum is %d \n ", machsize);
}
```

**Edit:**

I want to declare MyComm as global communicator for all the functions listed in my C code. But I don't know why my communicator is still invalid. Note that the MPI routines are initialized and finalized in Fortran only, I expect I don't have to initialize them in C again. I am using the following Fortran code.

```
     implicit none
      include 'mpif.h'
      integer :: MyColor, MyCOMM, MyError, MyKey, Nnodes
      integer :: MyRank, pelast
      CALL mpi_init (MyError)
      CALL mpi_comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, Nnodes, MyError)
      CALL mpi_comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, MyRank, MyError)
      MyColor=1
      MyKey=0 

   CALL mpi_comm_split (MPI_COMM_WORLD, MyColor, MyKey, MyComm,MyError)
   CALL ramcpl (MyComm)
   CALL mpi_barrier (MPI_COMM_WORLD, MyError)
   CALL MCTWorld_clean ()
   CALL mpi_finalize (MyError)
```

my subroutine `ramcpl` is located at another place

```
subroutine ramcpl (MyComm_r)
implicit none
integer :: MyComm_r, ierr
.
.
.
CALL par_init_fortran (MyComm_r, my_mpi_num,nmachs);
End Subroutine ramcpl
```

The command line and the output is,

```
    mpirun -np 4 ./ramcplM ramcpl.in

       Model Coupling: 

[localhost:31472] *** Process received signal ***
[localhost:31473] *** Process received signal ***
[localhost:31472] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[localhost:31472] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[localhost:31472] Failing at address: (nil)
[localhost:31473] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[localhost:31473] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[localhost:31473] Failing at address: (nil)
[localhost:31472] [ 0] /lib64/libpthread.so.0() [0x3120c0f7e0]
[localhost:31472] [ 1] ./ramcplM(par_init_fortran_+0x122) [0x842db2]
[localhost:31472] [ 2] ./ramcplM(__rams_MOD_rams_cpl+0x7a0) [0x8428c0]
[localhost:31472] [ 3] ./ramcplM(MAIN__+0xea6) [0x461086]
[localhost:31472] [ 4] ./ramcplM(main+0x2a) [0xc3eefa]
[localhost:31472] [ 5] /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd) [0x312081ed1d]
[localhost:31472] [ 6] ./ramcplM() [0x45e2d9]
[localhost:31472] *** End of error message ***
[localhost:31473] [ 0] /lib64/libpthread.so.0() [0x3120c0f7e0]
[localhost:31473] [ 1] ./ramcplM(par_init_fortran_+0x122) [0x842db2]
[localhost:31473] [ 2] ./ramcplM(__rammain_MOD_ramcpl+0x7a0) [0x8428c0]
[localhost:31473] [ 3] ./ramcplM(MAIN__+0xea6) [0x461086]
[localhost:31473] [ 4] ./ramcplM(main+0x2a) [0xc3eefa]
[localhost:31473] [ 5] /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd) [0x312081ed1d]
[localhost:31473] [ 6] ./ramcplM() [0x45e2d9]
[localhost:31473] *** End of error message ***
```

Answer (score 6):

The handles in Fortran and C are NOT compatible. Use MPI_Comm_f2c https://linux.die.net/man/3/mpi_comm_f2c  and related connversion functions. Pass it between C and Fortran as an integer, not as `MPI_Comm`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174220/discussion-on-answer-by-vladimir-f-segmentation-fault-error-due-to-mpi-comm-size).

Comment: I guess MPI_Comm_f2c will work well with F77 code but I am using F90.

Comment: F77 and F90 are the same in this regard.

Comment: The issue was with different mpi.h files and datatype of my Fortran handle. I converted it to MPI_ADDRESS_KIND and replaced the old mpi.h file. The code ran successfully. Thanks for all the efforts and help. :-)